# How to mutate some values of a dataframe based on values from another dataframe column with R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to transform `df1$x` using `df2$x` to obtain `df3`. But I am certainly wrong when using `mutate` this way.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(year = c(2019, 2019, 2020, 2020),
              x = c("0123", "0222", "0144", "0124"))
df2 <- tibble(x = c("22", "24"))

# I want to obtain
df3 <- tibble(year = c(2019, 2019, 2020, 2020),
              x = c("0123", "0222", "0144", NA))

# but this mutate does not work
df1 %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(str_sub(x,3,4) %in% df2$x & year == 2020, NA, x))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `x`.
#> x `false` must be a logical vector, not a character vector.
#> i Input `x` is `if_else(str_sub(x, 3, 4) %in% df2$x & year == 2020, NA, x)`.
Created on 2020-10-26 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: There are couple of (or more) similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024346/dplyrif-else-check-for-condition-and-insert-na-as-part-of-the-evaluation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708366/if-else-false-must-be-type-double-not-integer-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if_else` does type checks.  According to `?if_else`

> Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

and `NA` by default returns `NA_logical_`.

```
typeof(NA)
#[1] "logical"
```

According to `?NA`

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw. There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

We need `NA_character_` specifically as there is no coercing to appropriate type (which would normally work with `base R` `ifelse`)

```
typeof(NA_character_)
#[1] "character"
```

Therefore, it is better to use the appropriate type matched `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(x = if_else(str_sub(x,3,4) %in% df2$x &
              year == 2020, NA_character_, x))
```

The `ifelse` doesn't have that issue as the `NA` automatically is converted to `NA_character_`

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(str_sub(x,3,4) %in% df2$x & year == 2020, NA, x))
```

Comment: Great answer to otherwise obscure error message.